# second domain and '/'

Tags: subdomain

Let's say I have a domain `a.com` and a subdomain `a.a.com`

The folder of the subdomain is inside the main domain's folder, so accessing `a.com/a/` is the same as accessing `a.a.com`.

If an image in `index.php` of the subdomain has `url(/a/a.png)` instead of `url(a/a.png)`, when I load the subdomain `a.a.com`,

will there be any chance that I would download the image from `a.com/a/a.png` instead of `a.a.com/a/a.png` and result in an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested. It is safe to do so.